# Checkbox name can't pass to controller from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Checkbox in view page

```
using (Html.BeginRouteForm("ShoppingCart", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...
<input type="checkbox" name="removefromcart_@item.Id" class="remove-@item.Id" value="@(item.Id)" style="display:none;" />
...
}
<script>
   $("tr.cart-item-row > td > input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('input[type=checkbox].remove-' + this.value).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('input[type=checkbox].remove-' + this.value).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

So I want to pass name(removefromcart_@item.Id) of checkbox to controller.

But I can't handle it because when I submit the form, markup of checkbox delete(mean when we submit the form we dont get the name of checkbox in controller) so I can't get the name of checkbox in controller.

So please suggest how to  sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted, if checkbox is not checked then it won't be in the POST data. Need to search in the post data to make sure if checkbox is existing or not in the controller instead checking its value. Because again, if submitted without it is checked then it won't be in the post data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have submit form with checked checkbox without it I cant post it. and I have tried with hidden element but its doesn't work for while.

Comment: @Hrdk use visibility:hidden instead display:none in style.
display:none elements are not posted as I remember and it should help.

Comment: @Hrdk let me ask you, why don't you just use the originally checked checkbox for the row items? I would just set their names in array notation (name="item[12]" for example) with item ids and use as array with the corresponding itemIds in the server side. Easier to loop in the posted checkboxes with the posted ids.